# How to send mail using OctoberCms?

Tags: laravel, email, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

How to send Email in octobercms after form submission? i created a mail from backend mail template in octobercms the mail code is contact::form.

```
// $data has name and email 
        $to = System\Models\MailSettings::get('abc@gmail.com');
        Mail::sendTo($to, 'contact::form', $data);
        return true;
```

I'm getting this error :

> \Components\System\Models\MailSettings' not found

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're using `MailSettings::get('abc@gmail.com')` for, but you can remove that line and simply pass in the email address:

```
Mail::sendTo('abc@gmail.com', 'contact::form', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the mail system correctly to send mail?

[image]

What do you need the mail settings info for?
Remove that line. I believe that email will automatically be used unless you specify it in the Mail function.

I believe you need to add the Mail class (maybe input) to your component like so:

```
use Mail;
use Input;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, i used. SMTP, server:smtp.gmail.com, port 587, user :mygmailid, pass:mygmailpass

Comment: My site is hosted on godaddy shared hosting

Comment: Make sure you are using the Mail class in your component. And you probably need to use the input class as well.

use Input;
use Mail;